# Expand start and end date in sql Snowflake

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, recursive-query

I have the following issue:

In a snowflake database table I have a field called start date and another field called end date.

what I need is to expand their dates for each record, for example:

```
id | date_start | date_end 
1  | 2019-12-01 | 2019-12-05 
2  | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-06
```

the result should look like this:

```
id | date_new 
1  | 2019-12-01  
1  | 2019-12-02 
1  | 2019-12-03 
1  | 2019-12-04 
1  | 2019-12-05 
2  | 2020-01-01 
2  | 2020-01-02 
2  | 2020-01-03 
2  | 2020-01-04 
2  | 2020-01-05
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried yourself this far?

Comment: Try the code that marks as solution here and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte (id, date_start, date_end) as (
    select id, date_start, date_end from mytable
    union all
    select id, date_start + interval '1 day', date_end from cte where date_start < date_end
)
select id, date_start date_new from cte
```